# Why is patent for Viagra extended beyond term?

Tags: viagra

The patent for Viagra expired but has been renewed. Other patents expire in 20 years- why did they get extension?

Comment: What is your evidence that the patent was renewed?  A quick Google search shows no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

The patents cannot be renewed beyond 20 years. But what you are referring to is a **patent term** **extension**. I am not aware of other fields, but this is very common for **pharmaceutical products**. The reason for this extension is that a drug always requires long and tedious reviews before final approval and in many cases the final "ok" of the authorities for entering the market is 4-5 years before the patent is set to expire.
In US and Europe this patent term extension is linked to the time the authorities "delay" the approval. Other countries (Japan, Australia, S. Korea) have similar provisions in their laws too, but notably not Canada. In Europe this extension in called *Supplementary Protection Certificate*. As far as I have seen, this never exceeds 5 years, in other words the extension cannot result in an overall patent lifetime beyond 25 years. Mind that there are other provisions protecting the pharmaceutical product as well, but those are not linked to the patent of the drug, rather to the approval of the relevant authority.
The TPP draft agreement (at least one that I partially read last year) included provisions related to this practice, among other issues.

Comment: Yet I think that particularly for Viagra, the patent for the active pharmaceutical ingredient is older than 25 years. What is the patent you are referring to?